# django template is not showing python variables anymore

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

so I'm trying to build a website with Django (TAPP.GE), I'm getting texts for the website from the database, but after 39 variables, the 40th one and every variable after that is not showing up on the website.

all the texts above (get endless possibilities, etc are exactly the same type of variables as others but others are not showing up below, with 4 different icons.)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCTwK.png

this code works fine

```
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="appie-fun-fact-item">
                                                <h4 class="title">{{ video_bg_stat_3.content_eng }}</h4>
                                                <span>{{ video_bg_stat_title_3.content_eng }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

this code is not working even if I pass the same variables as above

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="appie-section-title text-center">
                        <h3 class="appie-title">{{ advantages_title.content.geo }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ advantages_subtitle.content.geo }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

so it works for the first 39 variables, after that it does not work.

Views.py

```
def home(request):
context = {
    'in_month': Text.objects.get(name="in_month"),
    'mainslogan': Text.objects.get(name="mainslogan"),
    'application': Text.objects.get(name="application"),
    'main_menu_1': Text.objects.get(name="main_menu_1"),
    'main_menu_2': Text.objects.get(name="main_menu_2"),
    'main_menu_3': Text.objects.get(name="main_menu_3"),
    'main_menu_4': Text.objects.get(name="main_menu_4"),
    'subslogan': Text.objects.get(name="subslogan"),
    'feedback': Text.objects.get(name="feedback"),
    'first_block_feature_1': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_feature_1"),
    'first_block_feature_2': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_feature_2"),
    'first_block_feature_3': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_feature_3"),
    'first_block_feature_4': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_feature_4"),
    'first_block_subtitle_1': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_subtitle_1"),
    'first_block_subtitle_2': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_subtitle_2"),
    'first_block_subtitle_3': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_subtitle_3"),
    'first_block_subtitle_4': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_subtitle_4"),
    'first_block_title_before_br_1': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_before_br_1"),
    'first_block_title_after_br_1': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_after_br_1"),
    'first_block_title_before_br_2': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_before_br_2"),
    'first_block_title_after_br_2': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_after_br_2"),
    'first_block_title_before_br_3': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_before_br_3"),
    'first_block_title_after_br_3': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_after_br_3"),
    'first_block_title_before_br_4': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_before_br_4"),
    'first_block_title_after_br_4': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_title_after_br_4"),
    'first_block_text_1': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_text_1"),
    'first_block_text_2': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_text_2"),
    'first_block_text_3': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_text_3"),
    'first_block_text_4': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_text_4"),
    'first_block_button': Text.objects.get(name="first_block_button"),
    'video_bg_title': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_title"),
    'video_bg_subtitle': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_subtitle"),
    'video_bg_stat_title_1': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_title_1"),
    'video_bg_stat_title_2': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_title_2"),
    'video_bg_stat_title_3': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_title_3"),
    'video_bg_url': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_url"),
    'video_bg_stat_1': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_1"),
    'video_bg_stat_2': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_2"),
    'video_bg_stat_3': Text.objects.get(name="video_bg_stat_3"),
    'advantages_title': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_title"),
    'advantages_subtitle': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_subtitle"),
    'advantages_box_title_1': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_title_1"),
    'advantages_box_title_2': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_title_2"),
    'advantages_box_title_3': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_title_3"),
    'advantages_box_title_4': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_title_4"),
    'advantages_box_subtitle_1': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_subtitle_1"),
    'advantages_box_subtitle_2': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_subtitle_2"),
    'advantages_box_subtitle_3': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_subtitle_3"),
    'advantages_box_subtitle_4': Text.objects.get(name="advantages_box_subtitle_4"),
}
return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

here is text model

```
class Text(models.Model):
name = models.TextField(('Name'),default="defname")
content_geo = models.TextField(('Input Georgian Text Here'),default="defgeo")
content_eng = models.TextField(('Input English Text Here'),default="defeng")
content_esp = models.TextField(('Input Spanish Text Here'),default="defesp")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Please post the actual code in the question instead of adding links to imgur. Check this [SO Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) for more details.

Comment: yes but I can't upload the whole code and for that parts, I think screenshots will be better than part of the code because I can't shrink code, it worked fine for first 39 and for 40th it does not work so I cant just post 3 or 4 lines and say this work and this does not

Comment: It would be ideal to put only relevant parts of the code. For example, lots of these context variables shown in your views code are irrelevant. Same for the non-circled parts of the HTML. Other relevant thing that is missing from the question and would give more clues to the solution would be the model code for Text model.

Comment: BTW, if any of the Text instances queried were missing in the database you would get an error in the view (`ObjectDoesNotExist`). So that should not be the issue.

Comment: that's definitely not the issue because I can use the variables that I said did not work in HTML code instead of older variables(that are above in the HTML code), I just can't add them

Comment: also, is it better this way? i mean edit with codes

Comment: could you add Text model to the question ?

Comment: @monim just added Text model

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is not working? Is the variable missing there or is it there in the HTML, but not visible? Can you inspect displayed HTML.

Comment: Thanks for adding the models. Looks like you have a typo in your code `content.geo` --> `content_geo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo just change `.content.geo` to `.content_geo` in your template .

**change   :**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="appie-section-title text-center">
                        <h3 class="appie-title">{{ advantages_title.content.geo }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ advantages_subtitle.content.geo }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**to :**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="appie-section-title text-center">
                        <h3 class="appie-title">{{ advantages_title.content_geo }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ advantages_subtitle.content_geo }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: i feel so dumb, i was trying to find out why it was not working for hour, thank you

Comment: it happens ! I asked you to add the  Model it self because everything looks fine must be something else  where the error is coming from